# How to split up an awk field into more fields using different separators?

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

Let's say I have `"a b user.group@server c /dir/foo/bar/last2/notneeded"`

Using awk, how can I print this out as:

`"a b user c server group /dir/foo/bar"`

Where I need to rearrange the order of some things as well as use different separators for each sub field and not include the last 2 pieces of path information within the directory structure?

My idea was to call `awk` on the output of my `awk` call, but that failed miserably.

EDIT for clarity:

Most of the data is space separated, but 2 of the fields have fields of their own. I want to be able to separate the `user.group@server` into 3 separate fields as well as truncate the last 2 pieces of the path in `/dir/foo/bar/last2/notneeded` to become `/dir/foo/bar`

Comment: *Will give +bounty in the future to anyone that can solve this.*---> No need of that, the interested ones will solve for free. I don't see a pattern here.

Comment: I added an edit for clarity, do you see what I mean now?

Comment: Read the manual. Look for `split`.

Comment: I tried split, but I couldn't reorder the split pieces afterwards.

Comment: `split` creates an array. You can print out the pieces of that array in any order you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to split fields in `user.group@server` since there are three fields for two type of separators. Instead you can use `match` and `substr`.

If you put the following in a.awk

```
 {
    sub(/\/[^/]*\/[^/]*$/, "", $NF)
    match($3, /.*\./)
    user = substr($3, RSTART, RLENGTH - 1)
    match($3, /\..*@/)
    group = substr($3, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
    server = substr($3, index($3, "@") + 1)
    print $1, $2, user, $4, server, group, $NF
}
```

and run

`awk -f a.awk foo.txt`

You will get

```
a b user c server group /dir/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple delimiters as well

```
 awk -F"[ .@]" '{print $1, $2, $3, $6, $5, $4, $7}'
```

which will return

```
a b user c server group /dir/foo/bar/last2/notneeded
```

for the last field, you can do the substitution by bkmoney.

```
 awk -F"[ .@]" '{sub(/\/[^/]*\/[^/]*$/, "", $7);print $1, $2, $3, $6, $5, $4, $7}'
```

returns

```
 a b user c server group /dir/foo/bar
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could define multiple field separators like that