# awk to extract days from line

Tags: awk

I have the following csv file

```
238013750030646-2;;"Default";"2020-10-01 00:40:36";;"opening";0;3591911;283940640
238013750030646-2;;"Default";"2020-10-03 00:40:36";;"closing line";0;89320;283940640
238013750030646-2;;"something-else";"2020-10-04 00:40:36";;"started";0;0;283940640
238013750030646-2;;"default else";"2020-10-08 05:42:06";;"opening";0;2410;283940640
```

Im trying to store each line in a specific file matching the date from each line, with the date being in the 4th column of each line, so first line (`"2020-10-01 00:40:36"`) should be in `output-01.csv`, second line in `output-03.csv` etc

This awk command

```
awk -F";|-" -vOFS='\t' '{print > "output-"$7".csv"}' testing.csv
```

half works but fails on line 3 because of the `-` in the 3rd column, and line 4 because of the   in the 3rd column - this produces `output-10.csv`

Is there a way to run the awk command twice ? then i could extract the date using the `;` separator and then split using `-`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split up an awk field into more fields using different separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546430/how-to-split-up-an-awk-field-into-more-fields-using-different-separators)

Comment: Could you please do explain for example on line `238013750030646-2;;"Default";"2020-10-01 00:40:36";;"opening";0;3591911;283940640` which exact digit you want to pick it up? Sorry its not clear you are saying it should be `output-01` so it will  be good if you could simply highlight which field you want, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have updated the question, apologies

Comment: @tripleee i did see that question, but i need to store the whole line and couldnt work out how to do that using the suggested answer for that question

Comment: There are several similar duplicates. My recommendation would be to use a single separator on the top level and then `split` on your secondary separator if you have fields with structured information.

Comment: Can your first quoted field ever contain a `;`, e.g. `"foo; bar"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
$ awk -F';' -v OFS='\t' '{split($4,a,/[- ]/); file = "output-"a[3]".csv";
                          $1=$1; print > file; close(file)}' testing.csv
```

- `split($4,a,/[- ]/)` this will split 4th field further based on space or `-` characters, saved in array `a`
- `file = "output-"a[3]".csv"` output filename
- `$1=$1` since there's no other command changing contents of input line, this is needed to rebuild input line, otherwise OFS will not be applied
- `print > file` print input line to required file
- `close(file)` calling close, useful if there are too many file names

You can also use `file = "output-" substr($4,10,2) ".csv"` instead of `split` if the 4th column is consistent as shown in the sample.

Comment: thanks for the explanation that really helps understand your answer

Comment: That will fail if/when the same date occurs for multiple input lines as it'll overwrite the output file for that date every time it occurs. It could also be done much more efficiently if we sort the input first by the timestamp field.

Answer (score 3):

Using **gawk** takes care of ***unsorted*** file too :

```
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/,arr){
          file=sprintf("output-%s.csv",arr[3]);
          if(!seen[file]++){
              print >file; 
              next         
          }     
     }{
        print >>file; 
        close(file);
     }' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/,arr){   # match for regex
          file=sprintf("output-%s.csv",arr[3]);          # file variable using array arr value, 3rd index
          if(!seen[file]++){                             # if not seen file name before in array seen
              print >file;                               # print content to file
              next                                       # go to next line          
          }     
     }{
        print >>file;                                    # append content to file 
        close(file);                                     # close file
     }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/){
  outputFile=substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)".csv"
  print >> (outputFile)
  close(outputFile)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/){   ##using match function to match yyyy-mm-dd here in line.
  outputFile=substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)".csv" ##Getting matched regex sub-string into outputFile here.
  print >> (outputFile)               ##Printing current line into outputFile here.
  close(outputFile)                   ##Closing output file to avoid too many files opened error.
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently you should sort on the key field first:

```
awk -F';' '{print $4, NR, $0}' file |
sort -k1,1 -k3,3n |
awk '
    { curr=$1; sub(/([^ ]+ ){2}/,"") }
    curr != prev { close(out); out="output-" (++c) ".csv"; prev=curr }
    { print > out }
'
```

```
$ head output*.csv
==> output-1.csv <==
238013750030646-2;;"Default";"2020-10-01 00:40:36";;"opening";0;3591911;283940640

==> output-2.csv <==
238013750030646-2;;"Default";"2020-10-03 00:40:36";;"closing line";0;89320;283940640

==> output-3.csv <==
238013750030646-2;;"something-else";"2020-10-04 00:40:36";;"started";0;0;283940640

==> output-4.csv <==
238013750030646-2;;"default else";"2020-10-08 05:42:06";;"opening";0;2410;283940640
```

The above will work using any awk+sort in any shell on every Unix box. See the many similar examples on this site for an explanation.